# Using Go in C++

Tags: c++, go, shared-objects, object-files

linux Debian Buster

go version go1.11.6 linux/amd64

gcc version 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-6)

**libmylib.go**

```
package main

import "C"

import (
    "fmt"
)

func say(text string) {
    fmt.Println(text)
}

func main(){}
```

**mylib.h**

```
#ifndef MY_LIB_H
#define MY_LIB_H

#include <string>

void say(std::string text);

#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <string>
#include "mylib.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string text = "Hello, world!";

    say(text);

    return 0;
}
```

> CGO_ENABLED=1 go build -o libmylib.so -buildmode=c-shared libmylib.go

> g++ -L/path/to/lib/ -lmylib main.cpp -o my-test-program

> /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccu4fXFB.o: in function 'main':
> main.cpp:(.text+0x53): undefined reference to `say(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >)' 
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

with change: `package main -> package mylib`

> CGO_ENABLED=1 go build -o libmylib.so -buildmode=c-shared libmylib.go

> -buildmode=c-shared requires exactly one main package

Comment: It might be much simpler to call C++ code from a go program. Is it possible for you to adapt your actual code to that situation ?

Comment: I need to use some functions from a Go file in my C ++ project. Because I don't know Go and, accordingly, couldn't translate Go -> C++

Comment: Please don't comment your question, but [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62977352/edit) it by providing some [mre]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `GoString` rather than `std::string` in the C++ version. The error message you are getting is because of the type mismatch, manifesting as a link-time error.

See [the cgo reference](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/#hdr-C_references_to_Go).

Here's a working example. There's a few differences from yours. The `//export` directive is needed to include the function in the generated header file, the argument is `*C.char` rather than `string` or `GoString`. The C++ code uses the header generated by cgo, and there has to be a const-removing cast from the static string (because go doesn't have C-like const).

#### libmylib.go

```
package main

import "C"

import (
    "fmt"
)

//export say
func say(text *C.char) {
    fmt.Println(C.GoString(text))
}

func main() {}
```

### main.cpp

```
#include "libmylib.h"

int main(void) {
    say(const_cast<char*>("hello world"));

    return 0;
}
```

### commands

This compiles to go file, generating `libmylib.so` and `libmylib.h` in the current directory.

```
go build -o libmylib.so -buildmode=c-shared libmylib.go
```

The compiles the C++ program, linking it to the shared library above:

```
g++ -L. main.cpp -lmylib -o hello_program
```

To run the program, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` needs to be set to the current directory. That would be different if program was installed and the shared library put in a sensible place.

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./hello_program
```

Comment: `go tool cgo libmylib.go` .
After that i got "_obj" folder .
**mylib.h** `extern void say(GoString text);` . **main.cpp** `GoString text = "Hello, World!";` .
>g++ -L/path/to/lib/ -lmylib main.cpp -o my-test-program.    
>main.cpp:5:21: error: conversion from ‘const char [14]’ to non-scalar type ‘GoString’ {aka ‘_GoString_’} requested    
GoString text = "Hello, World!";    
Changing to `extern void say(GoString text[]);` make no sense.

Comment: Yes, you can't create a value of type `GoString` from C++. Probably easiest is passing in a null-terminated C string (`char *` in C, `*C.char` in go), which you can convert in go to a go string using `C.GoString(s)`.

Comment: that means your go function would be: `func say(s *C.char) { fmt.Println(C.GoString(s)) }`

Comment: **libmylib.go** `func say( text *C.char ) { fmt.Println( C.GoString( text ) ) }` , **main.cpp** `char* text = "Hello, World!";` , **mylib.h** `extern void say(char* text);` . `>g++ -L/path/to/lib/ -lmylib main.cpp -o my-test-program`    `>main.cpp:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `say(char*)'` . For creating shared objects file im using the `>CGO_ENABLED=1 go build -o libmylib.so -buildmode=c-shared libmylib.go` command.

Comment: Any reason why you're not using the generated header file, as described in the cgo reference? But I guess at this point the answer to your current problem is in Basile's answer.

Comment: @Erop There's now a complete working example in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> g++ -L/path/to/lib/ -lmylib main.cpp -o test
> ```

is probably wrong. Read the [invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) chapter of the [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/). **Order of arguments to `g++` matters** a lot.

Also, [test(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html) could be some *existing* executable. I recommend to use some other name.

So consider compiling with

```
g++ -Wall -g -O main.cpp -L/path/to/lib/ -lmylib -o my-test-program
```

You probably want debugging information (`-g`), warnings (`-Wall`) and some optimization (`-O`)

You did comment

> I need to use some functions from a Go file in my C ++ project.

This is curious. I assume your operating system is some Linux. Then, can't you just use [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) facilities between a process running a Go program and another process running your C++ program? Consider perhaps using [JSONRPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC) or [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) between them. There exist several open source libraries in Go and in C++ to help you.

PS. As I commented, calling C++ code from a Go program could be much simpler. Of course you do need to read the [Go documentation](https://golang.org/doc/) and the [blog about `cgo`](https://blog.golang.org/cgo) and probably the [C++ dlopen minihowto](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/C++-dlopen/) and some [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp).